# PHP- FETCHALL fails due to big result returned

Tags: php, pdo

my fetchall  fails, since i have more than 10 000 000 rows in the result.
How can we treat bigger result by fetchall in this case ?
any ideas ?
thank you in advance
Tony

Comment: Why would you want to fetch 10 million records?

Comment: Missing data.
Which database? Why do you need all these records?

Comment: It make no sense to fetchall on such large datasets, you need to think more about what you are doing with the data and how you can break it down into a pipeline process (i.e. read a logical group of records/process/output - next block).

Comment: There should be no need to return this number of records all at once. It's not surprising it fails. What are you actually trying to achieve here? Maybe you need some sort of filtering or paging mechanism to (drastically) reduce the number of rows returned each time.

Answer (score 1):

As the others said it is a very bad idea to fetch so many datasets at once.
You either

- need to restrict your result or
- loop through the database by fetching a batch, processing it and fetching the next batch.

A `while` loop should be your friend.